# How to query an element collection from an entity using HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, embeddable

Anyone know how to query an element collection from an entity using HQL?
I'm trying to load all schedules from a given LiveTournament where the round is a certain number. I need a query like:

```
select m from MatchSchedule m where m.round=:round and m.tournament=:id
```

But this gives me an "is not mapped" exception, I presume because MatchSchedule is not an entity but an embeddable.

My LiveTournament entity is structured as so:

```
public class LiveTournament {
@Id
private int id;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="id")
@MapsId
private Tournament tournament;
private TournamentParameters parameters;
private TournamentRoundData roundData;

@ElementCollection
@JoinTable(name="MatchSchedule", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="tournamentId"))
private Collection<MatchSchedule> matchSchedules = new ArrayList<>();
...
```

And my MatchSchedule embeddable:

```
public class MatchSchedule {
private int round;
private Timestamp startDate;
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="server")
private Server server;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on your clarifications:

A model object needs the @Entity to say that it is a model object.  The Entity and Id are required.

so:

```
@Entity
class <modelName> {

   @id
   ...

}
```

You need to add an alias to your model in the from clause and add the alias to your select

so:

```
SELECT o FROM uk.xxx.dto.tournament.stages.LiveTournament o
```

Since there is no "where clause" I assume you plan to get a list of LiveTournament. I also assume you have a getter for matchSchedules.

```
    String hql = "select o from LiveTournament o";
    Query query = <*Your persistence context*>.createQuery(hql);
    List<LiveTournament> list = query.getResultList();
    for(LiveTournament l : list) {
        List<MatchSchedule> matchSchedList = l.getMatchSchedules());
        //do something with this list of matchSchedule
     }
```

Note: you can select into a List of mapped objects and retrieve back only what you want. Something like:

```
    String hql = "select m.<item1>, m.<item2>, ... from MatchSchedule m where ....;
    Query query = <*Your persistence context*>.createQuery(hql);
    List<Map<String,Object>> list = query.getResultList();
```

if a single item you can retrieve back into a map:

```
String hql = "select m.<item1>, m.<item2>, ... from MatchSchedule m where ....;
Query query = <*Your persistence context*>.createQuery(hql);
Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) query.getSingleResult()
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm after. I've updated the question to make it more clear exactly what it is I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Given the update what seems to be missing is the annotation @Entity before the class